# Is it possible to place the code folding icons in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The fold folding icons all appear next to the numbers on the leftmost edge. I would like them to be next to their indented guides. Is there a way to change that? I don't see anything in the settings. Is there an extension or perhaps a way I can extend my theme to do that?

I'm also already using the Guides extension and Colorize brackets, and while those are useful it would be nice to have the folding icons closer to where the actual guidelines are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible as of VS Code 1.24.

If this is something that you would like to see, please [file a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new)